# How to scale an SVG rectangle while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: svg

This might be a stupid question, but I just started playing with SVG's today, and am running into an issue.  I'm not sure if I'm just thinking about it the wrong way, or if I'm trying to do something that's not meant to work.

What I'd like to do, is create an SVG rectangle that has a height that is 30% of its width.  I'd like this SVG to scale within a `<div>`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to set a max height and width for the SVG to scale to, as well (1500x450, in this example).

Also, I'm trying not to use JavaScript to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG has a [preserveAspectRatio](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute. You stick it on the `<svg>` element and give it an appropriate value depending on how you want the aspect ratio preserved and it will do everything for you, no javascript required. You'll need a viewBox attribute set too, otherwise preserveAspectRatio is ignored.

Comment: Thanks!  The viewBox combined with preserveAspectRatio is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

In order for SVGs to scale properly, they need to have a viewBox attribute.  The viewBox attribute describes the bounds of the content.  Without it, a renderer (browser etc) has no way of working out how to scale the SVG to fill the parent.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 30">

   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" fill="orange" />

</svg>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zApv4/